# SQL Query hangs forever when joining on decimal(8,0) fields

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following query, which works fine:

```
SELECT      TMP_CLPUD.dbo.FormatS(RIGHT(SV1.VASLOC, 7), 9, 0) AS C_ACCOUNT, 
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.FormatS(Cust.C_CUSTOMER, 7, 0) AS C_CUSTOMER, 
        CA.OID, 
        CN2.NBCUNQ AS CUNQ, 
        CN2.NBSUNQ AS SUNQ, 
        'AC' AS C_STATUS,
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.mmsDATE(CN2.NBCNTE) AS IN_DATE, 
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.mmsDATE(CN2.NBDSTE) AS OUT_DATE, 
        0 AS ARCHIVE
FROM        BILLING.SVP00100 AS SV1 INNER JOIN BILLING.CNP00200 AS CN2 ON SV1.VASUNQ = CN2.NBSUNQ
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CMP00100 AS CM1 ON CN2.NBCUNQ = CM1.KACUST
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CustomerAccounts AS CA ON CM1.KACUST = CA.CustomerNbr
                                INNER JOIN TMP_CLPUD.dbo.tblCustomers As Cust ON CA.OID = Cust.OID
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.Customers AS C ON CA.OID = C.OID
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CNP00100 AS CN1 ON CN2.NBCUNQ = CN1.NACUNQ AND CN2.NBSUNQ = CN1.NASUNQ
ORDER BY C_ACCOUNT, C_CUSTOMER
```

However, if I try to link one more field between CN1 and CN2, the query will hang indefinitely. The field is type decimal(8,0) in both tables and does not allow for nulls. Here is the query with the third link in place:

```
SELECT      TMP_CLPUD.dbo.FormatS(RIGHT(SV1.VASLOC, 7), 9, 0) AS C_ACCOUNT, 
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.FormatS(Cust.C_CUSTOMER, 7, 0) AS C_CUSTOMER, 
        CA.OID, 
        CN2.NBCUNQ AS CUNQ, 
        CN2.NBSUNQ AS SUNQ, 
        'AC' AS C_STATUS,
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.mmsDATE(CN2.NBCNTE) AS IN_DATE, 
        TMP_CLPUD.dbo.mmsDATE(CN2.NBDSTE) AS OUT_DATE, 
        0 AS ARCHIVE
FROM        BILLING.SVP00100 AS SV1 INNER JOIN BILLING.CNP00200 AS CN2 ON SV1.VASUNQ = CN2.NBSUNQ
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CMP00100 AS CM1 ON CN2.NBCUNQ = CM1.KACUST
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CustomerAccounts AS CA ON CM1.KACUST = CA.CustomerNbr
                                INNER JOIN TMP_CLPUD.dbo.tblCustomers As Cust ON CA.OID = Cust.OID
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.Customers AS C ON CA.OID = C.OID
                                INNER JOIN BILLING.CNP00100 AS CN1 ON CN2.NBCUNQ = CN1.NACUNQ AND CN2.NBSUNQ = CN1.NASUNQ AND CN2.NBCNTE = CN1.NACNTE
ORDER BY C_ACCOUNT, C_CUSTOMER
```

I've rewritten this thing as many different ways as I could think but every time I try to link that third field it just hangs forever. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what lessons have we learned about using a floating point (however accurate) type as a join key today?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to compare floating point numbers for an exact match, you're usually asking for trouble.  One way to overcome this is to take the absolute value of the difference of the 2 numbers and compare it to an epsilon, say 1e-9, and if the difference is less than or equal to this epsilon, then you can assume the 2 floating point numbers are equal.

**EDIT**
As Lasse points out, it will be a mess to try and join these columns using the technique described above. If you really need this join capability, another approach would be to not store the numbers as floating point, but store them as integers. So if it were a dollar currency, for example, you could store $123.45 as 12345.  $99.01 would be stored as 9901.  Then you could join the integer values, which would avoid all the headaches with floating point numbers. To convert the integer numbers back to their corresponding floating point value, you just divide by some constant (100 in the dollar currency example).

But I would question why you are joining these types of values, it seems kind of weird.

Comment: Which is going to work wonders with a join. Can you say cross-join comparisons (note, not criticism to your answer, just an observation to the question in play here :))

Comment: @Lasse V. Karsen - Yes, I got to thinking about this after I posted my answer and wasn't sure of a good way to join them, so I agree with you :).  I guess this technique works pretty well in programming competitions, but not so much with SQL joins ;).

Comment: I agree though, it *is* the "correct" way of comparing floating point values. The problem here is the whole notion of joining on floating point values. There's a reason it's never done. Good answer though, doubt it helps the OP but then again I doubt anything will in this case :)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karsen - Yes, I agree also as I noted in my edit. It just doesn't seem right to be joining on "data" values, but then again, I don't have a clue what the OP is trying  to do. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the data type in the tables. This query is part of an SSIS package I designed for data conversion from a legacy billing system to our software. In actuality, it's a date value (such as 19930621) which I'm trying to compare. I have no idea why they chose to store it in a decimal field.

I'm really hoping to do this with a join because after this query runs, I need to then write the same query again but using an outer join on those tables where CN1 returns NULL (finding all values in CN2 that are absent in CN1).

Comment: How about creating materialized views with the correct data types, using conversion functions to build the view? This would give you a copy of all the data, only with the correct data types. Yes, this will slow down updates (of all types). However, joining on floating point values is *not* going to work fast.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used materialized views before. I'm really new to SQL (we only ever used Access up until a few weeks ago, but Access can't handle the DB sizes we're dealing with now).

I've created a view in SQL Server 2005 with the fields I need from these tables, but I'm not sure how I would represent a different data type in one of these fields. Am I just casting it?

Comment: I figured it out by narrowing the query down. For some reason it didn't like having the tblCustomers table in there, so I just ran an update afterwards to insert the customer number. The join on the floating point field worked fine after that for some reason. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Equality is always a little sketchy with floating point numbers.  If you're representing something like monetary transactions, you're usually better off storing them in an integer type, like cents (or tenths of cents, or whatever the smallest coin you're willing to deal with is).